# Open Single Button To Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

How can I open different pages from a single button by using a pair of two different dropdown menus?

[image]

```
<table  style="font-style:nunito; background-color:#FFEBF6;border:none;">  
    <tr>
    <td style="font-style:nunito; background-color:#FFEBF6;border:none;">
        <label style="font-size:20px; padding-bottom:10px;">My credit score is</label>  
        <select id="selectBox1">        
            <option value="excellent">Excellent (720 - 850) </option>
            <option value="good">Good (690 - 719)</option>
            <option value="average">Average (630 - 689)</option>
            <option value="poor">Poor (350 - 629)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    
    <td style="font-style:nunito; background-color:#FFEBF6;border:none;">
        <label style="font-size:20px; padding-bottom:10px;">I care most about</label>
        <select id="selectBox2">        
            <option value="a">Cash Back</option>
            <option value="b">Rewards</option>
            <option value="c">Travel</option>
            <option value="d">Balance Transfer</option>
            <option value="e">Low Interest</option>
            <option value="f">Building My Credit</option>
        </select>
    </td>
        
    <td style="font-style:nunito; background-color:#FFEBF6;border:none;"><br/>
        <input id="click" onclick="Redirect()" type="button" value="Find Cards" style="width:200px; height:45px; margin-top:5px;background-color: #2832C2;border:#415BA4;color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;"/>
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

The Find Cards button is not clickable. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: This button is clickable but you haven't define the function named Redirect()

Answer (score 0):

onclick of button this function will opens multiple pages

```
function Redirect() {
    window.open('url here', '_blank'); 
    window.open('url here', '_blank');
  }
```

Comment: I am sorry to say that but this function not work. Can you please help me to solve this issue through another way? Please once check my code if you see any error of that please tell me and please help me to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to make code with condition statement and when 2 value combination match it will open your desire url

try out this code

```
function Redirect(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var value1 =$('#selectBox1').val();
  var value2 = $('#selectBox2').val();
  if(value1 == "your value" && value2 == "your value"){
    window.open('your url', '_blank');
     
  }
  // repeate this if with your all combination of your value  and chage url 
  
  }
```